# Access to the creation of Glossary, Terms, Category, and Classification by different types of users. Apache Atlas

Tags: tags, classification, categories, glossary, apache-atlas

Please tell me if сan all types of users (e.g., admin, data scientist...) create the Glossary, Term, Category, and Classification in Apache Atlas?

I would also like to know whether it's possible to make any restrictions for some users for these purposes?

How can the Bookmarks and Popularity score be created in Atlas?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can control access in Apache Atlas.

1. Apache Ranger
2. Simple Authorization

Both are explained very well in following documents.

1. [Using Apache Ranger](https://atlas.apache.org/1.2.0/Atlas-Authorization-Ranger-Authorizer.html)
2. [Using Simple Authorization](https://atlas.apache.org/2.0.0/Atlas-Authorization-Simple-Authorizer.html)